# Move application to Websphere clusters

Tags: websphere, cluster-computing, application-server

What should we take care of before moving an application from a single Websphere Application Server to a  Websphere cluster

Answer (score 9):

This is my list from experience. It is not complete but should cover the most common problem areas:

- Plan head the distributed session management configuration (ie. will you use memory-to-memory or database based replicaton). Make a notice that if you are still on 32-bit platform the resource requirement overhead from clustering might cause you instability issues if your application uses already lots of memory.
- Make sure that everything you put into user sessions can be serialized with the default serializer (implements Serializable). You might otherwise run into problems with distributed sessions.
- The same goes for everything you put into DynaCache. Make sure everything serializes properly.
- Specify and make sure all the resource definitions (JDBC providers etc) will be made to a proper scope. I would usually recommend using the actual Cluster scope for everything that your applications installed to cluster use. That ensures the testing features work properly from proper points, and that you don't make conflicting definitions.
- Make sure your application uses relative paths for resources in web interfaces. Once you start load balancing and stuff you can run into some serious problems if you have bolted down a lot of stuff.
- If you had any sort of timers make sure they work well with clusters. With Quartz that means probably that you should use the JDBC store for timer tasks. With EJB Timers make sure you register the timers only once (it is possible to corrupt the timer database of WAS if you have several nodes attempting the registering at the exactly same time) and make sure you install them to Cluster scope.
- Make sure you use the WAS provided SSO mechanisms. If you have a custom implementation please make sure it handles moving the user between servers in cluster well.

Comment: +1 for `Make sure your application uses relative paths for resources in web interfaces. Once you start load balancing and stuff you can run into some serious problems if you have bolted down a lot of stuff.` IBM WebSphere Commerce 7

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple, depending on your requirements, try configuring your load balancer to use sticky sessions and not hold state in your HTTP Session. That way you don't need to use resource hungry in memory session replication.

Single Sign On isn't an issue for a single cluster as your HTTP clients will not be moving off the same http://server.acme.com/... host domain name.

Most of your testing should focus on database contention. If you have a highly transactional application (i.e. many writes to the same table) make sure you look at your database Isolation levels so that locks are not held unecessarily. Same goes for your transaction demarkaction. Keep transactions as brief as possible. If you dont have database skills yourself make sure you get a Database Analyst to help you monitor the database while you test.

Answer (score 0):

Also a good advice to raise a PMR to IBM Support up front of any major changes, such as this one or upgrading to new versions etc. Raise it as a "Software Usage Question" and they can provide you with feedback from their knowledge database based on other customers input. Same would apply for any type of product which you have a support agreement for - ask support before problems occur.